# Unable to combine :host-context with a :host /deep/ tag?

Tags: html, angular, sass

I am trying to build a double themed app using angular 2. The component css in question already uses :host /deep/ to force styling to child components.

However I am trying to toggle this styling based on the html theme, and am using :host-context.

I find that when I try to nest :host-context within a :host /deep/ tag, the changes from :host-context don't render.

E.g.

```
:host /deep/ .box {
    :host-context(.blueTheme) & {
        background-color: blue
    }
}
```

Any ideas on why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

`::slotted` is now supported by all new browsers and can be used with `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted

**original**

`/deep/` is deprecated. `::ng-deep` is the new thing.

I guess what you want is

```
:host-context(.blueTheme) /deep/ .box {
  background-color: blue
}
```

Comment: He uses `sass` tag so i suspect it is not css

Comment: @yurzui thanks I missed that - you're always paying more attention than I do :D

Comment: sorry, I'll try to be more modest :)

Comment: @yurzui no, no, don't be! :) It's better to fix bugs early, this way they cause less harm. I see your comments as code review.

Comment: much thanks, this works for me. so it was a syntax issue?and yes, correct this was scss

Comment: I think using `:host` together with `:host-context` makes `:host` redundant and that the `:host-context` isn't supposed to work at the place where you are using (in the middle of the selector).